# Importing from CSV to DataGridView without Scientific formatted numbers

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, csv, datagridview

I have a function which successfully loads data from a CSV to a datagridview. The problem is that there are very long numbers in some columns and they appear such as 5.00E+14. Ideally, I would like to change that value in the CSV file because I'm planning to export the CSV to another database. Any ideas?

```
Dim Lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(sFile)
        Dim Fields As String()
        Fields = Lines(0).Split(New Char() {","c})
        Dim Cols As Integer = Fields.GetLength(0)
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        '1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
        For i As Integer = 0 To Cols - 1

        dt.Columns.Add(Fields(i).ToLower(), GetType(String)).AllowDBNull = True
    Next
    Dim Row As DataRow
    ' = 1 to skip the first line
    For i As Integer = 1 To Lines.GetLength(0) - 1
        Fields = Lines(i).Split(New Char() {","c})
        Row = dt.NewRow()
        For f As Integer = 0 To Cols - 1
            Row(f) = Fields(f)
        Next
        dt.Rows.Add(Row)
    Next
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the formatting in the destination cells, either manually or using

```
Range("F7:G32").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

with whatever range and number format you want to use.  You can't change it in the csv file, because no matter how the number comes in, with the default general formatting in excel, it will display long numbers in scientific format.

Comment: I am trying to use VB.NET to display that formatted number on a datagrid in WinForms. Changing that in the CSV file won't help.